# rails-tutorialをしています。AWSで「Blocked host:」というエラーが出ました。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws

rails-tutorialをしているプログラミング初学者です。
チュートリアルを進めていくと、AWSのサーバーで「Blocked host:」というエラーが出ました。
このエラーを解決する方法を知りたいという質問です。

状況の詳細を書きます。
・rails-tutorialの第六版をやり始めた初学者です。
・第1章のチュートリアルを進めていき、「rails server」を実行するところまで動かし、そこで発生したエラーです。
・チュートリアルを進めていく過程で「/hello_app/config/environments/development.rb」に「config.hosts.clear」を追記せよ、と指示があったので指示通りにしました。
・エラーについて「rails-tutorial Blocked host」などで検索してみましたが、やはり上記の「config.hosts.clear」を書き足せとしか自分には見つけられませんでした。（あるいは自分の知識不足で理解できない解決方法が載っていて、それを理解するには何を理解すべきかもわからないほど難解でした。）
・他の原因も考えてみましたが自分に思いつけなかったので質問しました。

以上が、状況の詳細と解決したい問題点です。
もし不足している情報があれば書き足します。

以下に自分の予想も書きます。
development.rbファイルにはconfig.hosts.clearを書き足しただけで、そこから「保存？」のようなものはしていません。ただ記述しただけなので、何か保存のようなものが必要だったのかな、という予想は立てたので、調べてみましたが、うまく検索できませんでした。

画像も添付します。

ご回答いただけると嬉しいです。よろしくお願いします。[image: エラーが出た画像です。]

Comment: ~/rails-data/jquery1_samp/config/environments/development.rb\n
上記ファイルに下記項目を入れる事で私の場合は解決できています。
尚、メッセージも出ました。
 config.hosts << "サーバー名"\n       ##ruby3.0 rails6.1.3\n

Answer (score 0):

Blocked hostのエラーが出てから、development.rbにconfig.hosts.clearを追加して、その後何も操作していない状態と考えていいでしょうか？
もしそうでしたら、下段の真ん中の'puma'タブのところをクリックして、CTRL+C(キーボードのCTRLキーと同時にcを押してください)を押して(railsを停止して)、rails serverを書いて再度実行してみてください。どうなるでしょうか。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます

順番としては
・まず、development.rbに何も書かずにrails serverをじました。
・そしてエラー（block host）が発生しました。
・なので次に一度「control C」でサーバーを閉じました。
・次にdevelopment.rbに[config.host.clear]を追加しました。
・その後、再びrails serverをしました。

しかし、同じエラーが出ました。

ちなみに現状を報告します。
他に調べたことを様々試してみると「~.comに接続を拒否されました」と表示されていて、もはや元どおりにできないと思ったので、再び新しい環境？を作ってエラーが出た箇所までやり直しました。そして、同じエラー（block host）が出ました。

何か考えられる原因があれば教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 0):

rails6のチュートリアルは有料でしたので、rails5で試してみました。
まずlogをみて、一番下の行に
`Completed 200 OK`
が出ていたら、previewウィンドウのアドレスバーの一番右にある、四角に右上向きの矢印のあるアイコン(Pop Out Into New Window)をクリックすると、自分のブラウザから見られると思います。
数字が200(これはHTTPレスポンスステータスコードと言います)ではない場合は、どこかにエラーがあると思うので、別のトピックに改めてログを貼り付けていただければと思います。

Answer (score 0):

@innu さん

私もチュートリアルを進めていたところ同じ箇所で同じエラーが発生しました。

(AWS Cloud9でPreview Running Applicationを開いたところ、Blocked host:」と表示された状態です)

私の場合はAWS Cloud9上の Gemfile と development.rb を上書き保存(それぞれのファイルを開いた後に command + s)した後に、ubuntu:~/enviroment/hello_app $ bundle install を実行して、別タブにて rails server を実行したところ、先程のエラー画面が出なくなりました。

既に解決済みかもしれませんが、どなたかの助けになればと思い、コメントを残させて頂きます。

私自身はこの質問に巡り合えたことで、上記のエラーが自分だけに起きていることではないと分かり、落ち着いて対処することができました。ありがとうございます！